# how to edit htaaccess file rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

when i uploaded a file named ads.txt and go to it it shows 404 not found error :

404 Not Found

Error: The requested address '/ads.txt' was not found on this server.

The solution is on .htaaccess file but i dont know what i can change

I tried to change the .htaaccess file but it doesnt works

this is the .htaaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

#<Files ~ "\.(woff2|woff|ttf|otf|svg)$">
#    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#</Files>

# No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Comment the following line if you have not a .well-known directory in the root folder.
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

404 Not Found

Error: The requested address '/ads.txt' was not found on this server.

Comment: You write "The solution is on .htaaccess file"... How do you know that? Why do you write that? If you already know that then you can probably tell us what needs to be change. This leads to the question why you then cannot change it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

First solution is copying ads.txt file to /webroot/ folder (.htaccess rewrites all to /webroot/)

Second solution is add after `RewriteEngine on` line this RewriteCond that checks  request is not a file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```